# function is not defined conflicts in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, countdowntimer

I have a Javascript CountDown Timer which is called on a button click. The Javascript is defined in an external file. The CSS of timer is also an external file.

When I include javascript at start of page I got

> clock.queryselector is not a function

And when I include javascript at end of page I got

> initializeClock is not defined

Where should I keep this file. please help what am i missing ?

**HTML**

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<%-- <script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>

 </head>
 <body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
 <h3>Revervation Time Left</h3>
 <div id="clockdiv" runat="server"  style=" border: 1px solid red;">

   <div>
     <span class="minutes"></span>
     <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <span class="seconds"></span>
     <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div >
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
 </div>
</div>

  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>

  </form>

   <script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**Code**

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "myFunction", "initializeClock('clockdiv', 'Aug 10 2016 13:02:23');", True)
    'ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "none", "CallMe();", True)

End Sub
```

**Javascript**

```
 function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);

return {

    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
};
}

 function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  // alert(endtime);
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);

var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);


    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
}

updateClock();
var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}
```

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

Comment: Is initialiseClock getting called when you click the button, or does it fire before then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check why you are getting clock.queryselector is not a function this error.

there is something in your JS file which is missing, If you can address it. it will help you.

when you are including JS file at bottom you are getting error as function was called but not exists. so better option it to put at top only.

Comment: when i put it on the top, at that time the html is not rendered completly and it throws `clock.queryselector is not defined`. so i put it in the bottom and it's fixed. but then it throws that second error.

Comment: @abdul What he mean is : You should put it at the begining.
The error : clock.queryselector can be fixe and you should focus on debuging it

Comment: @ssbb : can you please suggest how it could be fixed ?

Comment: your code looks correct, I expect the error append because the getElementById return something falsy, and then you try to call on it which will fail. 
You should console.log(clock) and see if everything is all right at this step. Which I doubt

Comment: @ssbb : Thank you Dear. It worked. I put it on the beginning. still confused why it was not working when i put it on top before.

Comment: @user3844820 Thanks to you too :)